# How do find a row which has all duplicate values and delete it

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

Suppose we have a row like this

```
--------------------
a a a a a a b a a a 
a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a b a a a
```

I want the first and the third row to be delete, all the row values need to be the same but nothing else. How can I do that?

```
# Converting d to pandas Data Frame
dfObj = pd.DataFrame(d_balanced)

# Checking for duplicates
doop = dfObj.duplicated().any()
print(doop)


# Remove duplicates and verify
dooopie = dfObj.drop_duplicates().duplicated().any()
print(dooopie)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter rows where the number of unique values is exactly 1 with `nunique`:

```
df.loc[df.nunique(axis=1).eq(1)]
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
1  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple function that takes in the row as a string or list tec. Then you store the first letter or whatever it is and iterate over all the remaining elements. If one of them doesn't match the first elements (stored in a variable or accessed directly by index) return false, else return true.

Comment: No idea how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Compare the first column with all other columns to get a `mask(True/False)`. Now you want to keep a row if all the values in the mask are true for that row, so you do `mask = mask.all(axis = 1)`, which is True only if all the values along `axis=1`(all the value in a row) are True. Use this mask to select rows using `df[mask]`

Use:

```
mask = df.eq(df.iloc[:, 0], axis = 'index').all(axis = 1)
df = df[mask]
```

Comment: Will this work if the columns have unique values, and not all 'a' as I wrote ?

Comment: `columns have unique values` means? I am only keeping the row which doesn't have same value across all the columns.

Comment: as in a b c  is same as a b c, will that eliminate that ?

Comment: You also want to drop the duplicate rows?

Comment: Check @AnuragDhadse answer. Looks like you just want to drop the duplicate rows.

Comment: so, yea, it has to be duplicate rows and not columns. And it should check all the columns values in every row first and match it to other columns.

Comment: @IshaanSingh If other answer works. I will delete this.

Comment: It gives me error saying that the data frame has no attibute 'iolc'

Answer (score 0):

`drop_duplicates` has a parameter `keep` which keeps one of the duplicates found, setting it to `False` will effectively remove any duplicates

```
df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Result:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   a   a   a   a   a   a   a   a   a   a
```